# Android not restoring widgets correctly upon restoring focus

Tags: android, focus, widget, resume, stateful

I'm developing a rather GUI heavy android app and it has lots of little widgets (text fields, buttons etc..) which are dynamically configured at runtime. Everything is working well enough when the application has focus however once the user pushes the app to the background and restore it, all the widgets lose their dynamic state and revert back to their default state defined by their layout. Is this the proper behavior of Android apps?

I've developed numerous UIs on other platforms (iOS, Windows, Mac) and I've never seen behavior like this.. Do i have to do some magic dance to make Android keep the widgets state between re-focus? Any tips would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to look at the [lifecycle of an activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Basically, you need to save state in an onPause() function, and restore it with an onResume() function.

Comment: I sensed that was going to be the answer :(, manually saving widget state.. Why on all other OS this is done for you but for Android I have to manually save widget states? It feels like the 1990s all over again.. Thanks!

Comment: You could just do the configuration in the onResume() command instead of onCreate() (Not sure if you are doing that, but...), and it should act the same. More specific, I'd need to get a better idea of how your program looks...

Comment: My program is very dynamic the application state is defined by an external scripting system. On startup the program binds all the widgets and exposes them to the scripts which does all the dynamic configuration (ie set visibility, color and text ).. Obviously writing a script which also has to take into account Android quirks would be overly complex so I'll just make sure the widgets state are saved between onResumes.. I literally have like 100 widgets..